# UITableView using UIRefreshControl either Won't Finish or has Flicker/Jump under iOS11

Tags: iphone, uitableview, swift3, uirefreshcontrol

I have searched multiple discussions/examples for hours re UITableView using UIRefreshControl, and found most predate iOS11, and fall into one of two basic implementations, neither of which are working for me. Either I pull down and it won't finish (i.e., control slides with spinning wheel, and swiping up merely bounces it back down - yes, I'm using .endRefreshing); or it successfully completes but not before flashing large title on top of control (with original title still pulled down), and table cells jump up and down.

I am using Storyboard, and checking the enable box.  I am placing the code in ViewDidLoad, and have tried declaring a custom var outside and inside ViewDidLoad (as well as not using one, but that seems incorrect).  In ViewDidLoad, I have tried using tableView's .refreshControl, as well as .addSubview.  In the selector func, I have tried placing .reloadData above and below .endRefreshing.  Every variation produces one of the above two incorrect behaviors.

I am new to all of this, and completely frustrated, as all I'm trying to do is learn how to implement the feature on an iPhone.  I saw a post stating UIRefreshControl does not work as of earlier this month, but I find it hard to believe that Apple would just leave this rudimentary and ubiquitous feature broken for weeks+.  Can anyone please help?  Thanks, and happy holidays!

Comment: Apple's own native apps (e.g. Mail) have exactly the same problem, so it is probably not something that can be solved.